# How to create a https binding for a wcf service?

Tags: wcf

I have inherited a service which has been running on an intranet for a while. Security was never an issue but I have been asked if I could expose it to the internet.

### Binding definitions

The `LeanBinding` binding was inherited while the `SecureLeanBinding` is my guess.

```xml
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>

                <binding name="LeanBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                    </binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
                </binding>

                <binding name="SecureLeanBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">             
                    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                    </binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"></httpsTransport>
                </binding>

            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
```

### Client Endpoints

I copied the existing endpoint, but changed the address to use https and the binding configuration to use SucereLeanBinding.

```xml
        <client>

           <endpoint address="http://localhost/APP.Service/" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="LeanBinding" contract="APP.IService" name="customBinding_IService" />

           <endpoint address="https://localhost/APP.Service/" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureLeanBinding" contract="APP.IService" name="SecureBinding_IService" />

        </client>
```

### Service Behavior

I Set `httpsGetEnabled` to `true`

```xml
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>

                <behavior name="LeanEndPointBehaviour">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>

            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>

                <behavior name="LeanServiceBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>

            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

### Protocol Mapping

The protocol mapping does not seem to affect the behavior of the service. But I included it for completeness.

```xml
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureLeanBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>
```

### Service Definition

I added the second endpoint and baseAddress.

```xml
        <services>
            <service name="APP.ServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="LeanServiceBehaviour">

               <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" contract="APP.IService" behaviorConfiguration="LeanEndPointBehaviour" bindingName="LeanBinding" bindingConfiguration="LeanBinding" >
                   <identity>
                       <dns value="localhost" />
                   </identity>
               </endpoint>

               <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" contract="APP.IService" behaviorConfiguration="SecureLeanEndPointBehavior" bindingName="SecureLeanBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureLeanBinding" >
                  <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                  </identity>
               </endpoint>

               <host>
                   <baseAddresses>
                       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/APP.Service/" />
                       <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443/APP.Service/" />
                   </baseAddresses>
               </host>
          </service>

        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The http bindings work but the https bindings does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you host the service? the `HTTP` service endpoint requires the transport security mode and a certificate to secure the communication.  We should bind the certificate to the port of the server. If in IIS, it could be completed by the IIS website binding module.
[image]
The base address is unnecessary in the configuration file.

```
   <host>
                   <baseAddresses>
                       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/APP.Service/" />
                       <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443/APP.Service/" />
                   </baseAddresses>
               </host>
```

It needs to be done in the IIS site binding module.
If in a console application or it is self-hosted, we should bind a certificate to the specific port by means of below command.

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: For completeness the certhash can be found in the details tab of the certificate as the Thumbprint field. The following can be used to get the appid `string appid = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<GuidAttribute>().Value.ToUpper()`

Comment: Honestly speaking, APPID can be any string. But you have a great way to get the actual AppID.